# Modifying <Style> from code

Tags: silverlight

I need to modify a Style in resources from code.  I already know I can access the Setters like that :

```
 Style st = (Style)this.Resources["myStyle"];
 set.Setters.Etc...
```

But I need to change the value of a specific Setter in that style.  Is there any way to do it?

Also, how can I retrieve the appropriate setter in the setters list based on the "Property"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be the "cleanest" way, but I found out somthing that actually works :

```
Style myStyle = (Style)this.Resources["myStyle"];

SetterBase sb = myStyle.Setters.FirstOrDefault(z => (z as Setter).Property == Rectangle.FillProperty);
int iSetterIndex = myStyle.Setters.IndexOf(sb);

myStyle.Setters[iSetterIndex] = new Setter(Rectangle.FillProperty, newScrollThumbBackground);
```

It seems like I can't replace the value of the setter so instead I just find the old Setter index using property.  Then replace the setter at the found index by a new Setter object.

Comment: This is usually the way to go. Beware that your `z` is not necessary a `Setter`, it can be an `EventSetter` (at least in WPF), so a more safe way would be `z => (z is Setter) && ((z as Setter).Property == Rectangle.FillProperty)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this must do:

```
SetterBase sb = style.Setters[0];
Setter s = (Setter)sb;
s.TargetName = "abcd";
```

(at least in WPF)

**Edit:**
In Silverlight there's no `TargetName`, but you can still access `Property` and `Value`. So, you say something like `if (s.Property == Button.IsEnabled) s.Value = false;`.

**Edit:**
Oh, you found a better solution yourself. :-) Didn't know that it's not allowed to change the `Value`.

Comment: s.TargetName does not exist in Silverlight.  Also, I'd like to be able to change the value.  But now my main problem is how to retrieve the Setter by Property.